# How to configure AWS Route 53 to get equivalent of domain forwarding with masking

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

(I apologize in advance for not having enough technical depth to ask this intelligently)

I currently have an AngularJS static website hosted on AWS S3. I'm using AWS Route 53 for DNS. I'm able to successfully access the site through the browser (e.g. `example.com`) like this:

- `example.com`
- `example.com/siteA`
- `example.com/siteB`

What I want to achieve is to register `exampleA.com` and `exampleB.com` to get to this:

- `example.com` (as it currently is)
- `exampleA.com` (points to the siteA content without showing "`/siteA`" in the URL)
- `exampleB.com` (likewise points to `/siteB`)

I've done this before with GoDaddy's domain forwarding with masking, but I can't figure out how to do this with Route53 and I can't find it in their docs. And since this is a static S3 website I cannot add a server to the mix to do the routing there (at least that's my understanding).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon Route 53 cannot do this. Route 53 is a DNS service and masking is not a function of DNS.

Since the website is already stored on Amazon S3, simply create 2 buckets, one for exampleA.com and one for exampleB.com, each holding their own sites without the subfolders.

Comment: Since Route 53 does many things that aren't DNS I was hoping they had some functionality to support this.Your suggestion is probably my only non-server-code option. I'll have to see if I can come up with some clever way to share the huge percentage of shared code & assets. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy's domain forwarding with masking is not DNS, it is a reverse web proxy.

You'll need a VPS to do this yourself or find another service. (GoDaddy's seems reliable enough for domains you want to mask, you do not need to use GoDaddy DNS to accomplish this [Godaddy Forwarding](https://www.godaddy.com/help/manually-forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name-422).)

Other useful Info on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_masking)

Also to rephrase your question, you want to look at virtual-hosts, to point those domains to subfolders, post a new question with the relevant info (IIS, Apache, Litespeed)