# How to forward and mask requests using Amazon AWS?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, routing

**Setup**

I own the domain `examplefrontend.com`. I currently use Amazon's Route 53 to route `test.examplefrontend.com` to a S3 bucket of the name `test.examplefrontend.com`

I have a server setup at `exampledataapi.com`. I can `GET exampledataapi.com/orders` to get a list of orders and `GET exampledataapi.com/customers` to get all customers.

**Goal**
I want to forward `test.examplefrontend.com/api/orders` to `exampledataapi.com/orders`. `test.examplefrontend.com/api/xyz` should forward to `exampledataapi.com/xyz`. Which service of Amazon should I use?

**I've Read the following**
I've read the following and have a feeling that Route 53 cannot mask domains (at least to my limited understanding and it being clearly stated in some of the answers below). My colleagues feel otherwise, hence all this research. I've also tried using Traffic policies using the visual flow chart.

- [What is domain masking](https://whenihavetime.com/2008/11/11/what-is-domain-masking-domain-masking-in-plain-english/)
- [Routing to EC2 Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html)
- [DNS Forwarding Using Route 53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115799/set-up-dns-based-url-forwarding-in-amazon-route53)
- [Domain Forwarding with Masking in Route 53](https://serverfault.com/questions/720152/how-to-configure-aws-route-53-to-get-equivalent-of-domain-forwarding-with-maskin)
- [Another StackExchange question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/91681/can-i-use-route-53-with-amazon-aws-to-mask-a-subdomain)

Comment: CloudFront is suitable for this sort of proxying.

Comment: @ceejayoz Will check it out.